# Root Element is missing at System.Xml..XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocument

Tags: vb.net, xml-parsing, devexpress, memorystream

I am currently receiving the following exception (root element missing) when I am trying use load a bitmap into a devexpress GUI item. I have a function that performs

```
Public Function GetStreamFromBitmap(bitmapImage As Bitmap) As Stream
  Dim memStream As New IO.MemoryStream
  bitmapImage.Save(memStream, bitmapImage.RawFormat)
  Return memStream
End Function

Public Function CreateSvgShape(ByVal nameID As String, ByVal display As String, ByVal bitMap As Bitmap) As ShapeDescription
  Return ShapeDescription.CreateSvgShape(nameID, display, GetStreamFromBitmap(bitMap)).
     Update(getDefaultSize:=Function() New System.Windows.Size(100, 100)).
     Update(getConnectionPoints:=Function(w, h, p) {New System.Windows.Point(w / 2, h / 2)})
End Function
```

I am using a bitmap image from my resources file and I am trying to take it and put it into a IO.Stream. So that way I can use the stream to point to my picture within my resources file with a DevExpress control that uses it to find the file to load into their control. During the process the XML Parse Document can't find the picture inside the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The [ShapeDescription.CreateSvgShape](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressDiagramCoreShapeDescription_CreateSvgShapetopic) method documentation says:

> svgStream: a System.IO.Stream object that contains the SVG image.

but you have passed the Bitmap **binary** data(raster image format) rather than [SVG-data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)(XML-based vector image format).
So, to fix the exception, you should use this method as intended.

Comment: Then what is the proper way to pull the need information from a image from the My.Resources.Image?

Comment: As I have already mentioned, you should use vector resources instead of raster bitmaps. There is no conversion from raster to vector because of they are different worlds. Take a look at [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bitmap image rather than a SVG file, but ShapeDescription.CreateSvgShape is expecting a SVG format.

DevExpress UI item usually has a Glyph property and you can convert your image in resource like this:

```
xxx.Glyph = CType(resources.GetObject("image.bmp"), System.Drawing.Image)
```